# How to prove forall x y, x<=y -> div2 x <= div2 y in coq?

Tags: coq

I would like to prove this lemma “forall x y, x<=y -> div2 x <= div2 y” in coq by induction, however I got stucked.

How can I prove this by induction? Thanks!

I tried to prove by induction both on x and y, but all of them stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is to do a two-steps induction.

```
Lemma nat_double_ind (P:  nat -> Prop):
  P 0 -> P 1 -> (forall n, P n -> P (S (S n))) -> forall n, P n.
Proof. 
   intros H0 H1 HSSn; 
   assert (H : forall n, P n /\ P (S n)).
   { induction n. 
     - split; auto.
     - destruct IHn; split; auto. 
   }
    intro n; now destruct (H n). 
Qed.
```

Applying this principle, you can prove simple properties of `div2`.

```
Lemma L1: forall n, Nat.div2 (S (S n)) = S (Nat.div2 n).
Proof.
  induction n using nat_double_ind.
  1,2: reflexivity.
  rewrite IHn; now simpl. 
Qed. 

Lemma L2: forall n :nat,  Nat.div2 n <= Nat.div2 (S n).
(* ... *)
```

Lemma `L2` easily entails `div2`'s monotony.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the definition of `div2`:

```
Require Import Arith.
Import Nat.

Print div2.
(*
div2 =
fix div2 (n : nat) : nat := match n with
                            | S (S n') => S (div2 n')
                            | _ => 0
                            end
*)
```

The recursive case uses the predecessor of the predecessor, so it is not surprising that a simple induction won't work easily.

How would you prove this on paper?

---

Anyway, in order to get it in Coq, assuming this is not an exercise, you can always look for library lemmas to help you out. Here was my process:

```
Search div2 (_ <= _).
```

It doesn't seem very helpful, there are only two lemmas with both of these objects, and none does the trick... Hmm, `div2` is a special case of division, so maybe there are results on division that can help.

```
Search (_ / _) (_ <= _).
(* ... among others:
Div0.div_le_mono: forall a b c : nat, a <= b -> a / c <= b / c
*)
```

Bingo, this is a more general case of what we want. Now we just need to translate `div2` to `_ / 2`:

```
Search div2 (_ / _).
(*
div2_div: forall a : nat, div2 a = a / 2
*)
```

And that's it, with those two lemmas you get a proof.

---

I haven't thought about how to do it without relying on previous lemmas, but if you're curious, you can always track down the proof of `Div0.div_le_mono` in the Coq sources. This is admittedly not trivial. After some looking, I believe it is based on [this lemma](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/18722d285c34aee39f344c080ccfebe02fd974ba/theories/Numbers/NatInt/NZDiv.v#L274).